Failure reading Multipart Record due to new line in Header
I'm reading a multipart http record that starts like:
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=-ApvscWED/jbzvUC1B6nVqg=="

--=-ApvscWED/jbzvUC1B6nVqg==
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename=20240702225857-FSBC000000479793.json
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

eyJCYXJjb2RlIjoiRlNCQzAwMDAwMDQ3OTc5MyIsIk9yZGVyTm8iOiJGU0JDMDAwMDAwNDc5Nzkz
IiwiUmVmZXJlbmNlTm8iOiJGU0JDMDAwMDAwNDc5NzkzIiwiV2VpZ2h0IjoiMC4wMiIsIkNvbnNp
Z25lZUNpdHkiOiJDQUxHQVJZIiwiUGFyY2VsQ2l0eUxvY2F0aW9uIjoiQ2FsZ2FyeSIsIkNvbnNp

I have the following to read the content
    var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(contentType), 4096);
    Stream contentStream;
    try
    {
      contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to read content stream.");
    }
    
    var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, contentStream);

    MultipartSection? section;

    while ((section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync(cancellationToken)) != null)
    {
      var contentDisposition = section.GetContentDispositionHeader();
      // do more stuff to handle the data content

I am getting an error on the ReadNextSectionAsync call saying System.IO.InvalidDataException: Invalid header line:   filename=20240702225857-FSBC000000479793.json.
It appears that the read is failing due to the \r\n in the Content-Disposition header. How can I read the content and parse the response correctly?
